# Is there such thing as a CodeMirror for Xcode? I want to implement a code view in my Xcode 8 Swift 3 project. How do I implement it too?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8, codemirror

I need a way to implement an alternative or adapter for CodeMirror so that I can have a semi-advanced code editor, and some way to implement it in Xcode 8 Swift 3. Thanks!

Comment: You can add a `WKWebView` to your app. That would allow you to hose any Javascript application

Answer (score 0):

I’m not totally clear on what you want to do, but perhaps creating your CodeMirror editor in an app extension for XCode would do what you want?

Watch this WWDC presentation about that: [Using and Extending the Xcode Source Editor](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc16/414) from WWDC 2016.